# PHP - Use of Traits to share properties only

Tags: php, oop, traits

I have an application with many classes in my Model, and each class has many properties.
Most of these classes share some properties, but in such a way that creating a class hierarchy using only single inheritance is not really suitable.

So I started creating some Traits containing only properties, without methods, such as:

```
trait Dateable {
    protected $strat_date;
    protected $end_date;
}

trait Featurable {
    protected $image;
    protected $description;
}

trait Buyable {
    protected $price;
    protected $buy_link;
}
```

etc... And then I define my classes like:

```
class Film {
    use Featurable;
    // some own properties...
}

class Showing {
    use Dateable, Bookable;
    // some own properties...
}

class Course {
    use Featurable, Dateable, Bookable;
    // some own properties...
}
```

This allows me to have a more organised model of classes, but I was wondering if this is a *correct* use of Traits because I can't find any examples of this...

Is not there any reason (e.g., performance) to avoid doing this?

Comment: Sure, it's *a* possible use of traits.

Comment: Thanks @deceze, so in principle there's no reason (e.g.,performance-related) to stop doing this, right?

Comment: Not that I could think of.

Comment: Since all your properties are `protected`, creating traits for just properties doesn't seem like a great idea. At the very least, you also want to include the methods that actually reference these properties.

Comment: @Duroth, actually all my classes extend an `AbstractEntity` class that provides magic `__get()` and `__set()` methods, so that's not an issue... I omitted that for simplicity while exposing the important question...

Answer (score 2):

It's incorrect in terms of OOP, because pure OOP suggests that you encapsulate everything possible. In general words, you should not have any public properties. All object's data should be accessible only by object's methods.

In your example, you have `protected` everywhere, but that is still a little bit incorrect, since it makes your code coupled on that trait meaning that you might get problems if you will try to disable it.

But if you will add getter-setter, then you are OK.

In fact, making those getters and setters abstract will ensure that your objects will be trully "Dateable, Featureable, Bookable, etc.".

A little bit better example would be trait called `jsonParsable` that has  `abstract function toJson()`. Each class probably will have his own rules for returning JSON represenation, so it is good to make this trait abstract.

Comment: As I said in a comment above, all my classes extend an `AbstractEntity` class that provides magic `__get()` and `__set()` methods, so my properties are accesible via a method... Obviously, whether to use magic methods or concrete getters and setters is also a big discussion, but that's not the point of this question...

Comment: I'm not sure I get how do you use __get() with trait. Does it return some attribute or has some logic? In case it has some logic, does it know about possible traits in advance?

Comment: Not, at the moment they don't have any logic, at all... In the case I need any logic, I create a proper getter, and if the property that needs the getter with logic is in a Trait, I'll put the getter in the Trait, which is where it fits better...

Comment: ok, until you can't access something that is really should be private for your class from outside, then why not? What I'm trying to say, is that the main idea here is to make trait decoupled from your classes, make those classes be able to work without trait and make trait focused on it's own task. Until those are true your approach is good. As you said, we are discussing only traits and not the usage of magic methods.